# C code seems to work, but valgrind says an array is not initialized

Tags: c, token, valgrind

I'm currently working on a project in which I make my own tokenizer. My code compiles and works fine, however valgrind is giving the error:

```
==2572== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==2572==    at 0x4C2B308: strlen (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2572==    by 0x400FCB: strdup (Lex1.c:173)
==2572==    by 0x400EBA: lex (Lex1.c:140)
==2572==    by 0x400A3B: main (mainLex.c:34)
==2572== 
==2572== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==2572==    at 0x4C2B35B: strcpy (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2572==    by 0x400FFC: strdup (Lex1.c:177)
==2572==    by 0x400EBA: lex (Lex1.c:140)
```

Line 140 in lex is the "temp->text" line in the following code:

```
token *head, *temp, *right, *temp1;
char *line1 = strdup(line);
char *curr = separatebetter(line1);
temp = (token *)malloc(sizeof(token));
temp->text=strdup(curr);
```

The strange thing is that I can print the value of curr, but valgrind, by my assumptions, is saying that curr is not initialized at any point, although I clearly initialize it.

The two lines that valgrind references in strdup are:

```
int n = strlen(str) + 1;
strcpy(dup, str);
```

And the relevant code for separatebetter is:

```
char *separatebetter (char *arr)
{
    int status=0;
    static char* perm;
    if (arr!=NULL)
    {
        perm=arr;
    }
    if((perm[0]=='\0')||(perm[0]=='\n'))
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    if (strcspn(perm, "<|>&")==0)
    {
        status=1;
    }
    if (strcspn(perm, ";()")==0)
    {
        status=2;
    }
    char *toke = perm;
    char *temp;
    //Status is set to 1 or 2
    if (status==1)
    {
        printf("here\n");
        temp=toke;
        char *temp1=malloc(strlen(temp)*sizeof(char));
        temp1=temp;
        char *final = malloc(3*sizeof(char));
        temp1++;
        if(temp[0]==temp1[0])
        {
            final[0]=temp[0];
            final[1]=temp[0];
            *temp='\0';
            temp++;
            *temp='\0';
            perm=temp+1;
            return final;
        }
        else
        {
            final[0]=temp[0];
            final[1]='\0';
            *temp='\0';
            perm=temp+1;
            return final;
        }
    }
    else if (status==2)
    {
        temp=toke;
        char *final = malloc(2*sizeof(char));
        final[0]=temp[0];
        final[1]='\0';
        *temp='\0';
        perm=temp+1;
        return final;
    }
    perm[0]='\0';
    return toke;
}
```

EDIT: I've tried to printf curr, and although I get an output, valgrind still tells me that

```
==6625== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==6625==    at 0x4E7AB5B: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==6625==    by 0x4E83CD8: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==6625==    by 0x400EA8: lex (Lex1.c:138)
==6625==    by 0x400A3B: main (mainLex.c:34)
```

Am I wrong in thinking that the initialization of curr is the issue?

Comment: This is wrong: `char *curr = malloc(100*sizeof(char));
curr = separatebetter(line1);`  . You immediately leak the allocated memory and set `curr` to point somewhere else. Same thing happens with `temp1`.

Comment: Show the code you're actually testing. To get better help post a MCVE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is clearly wrong:

```
char *curr = malloc(100*sizeof(char));
curr = separatebetter(line1);
```

You allocate memory, and then overwrite the only pointer to it with a value from `separatebetter()`.  That's an immediate leak.  Maybe you intended to use `strcpy()`?

```
strcpy(curr, separatebetter(line1));
```

I'll need to look at what `separatebetter()` does — but this isn't your running code because it won't compile:

```
if (strcspn(perm, ";()")==0)
{
    status=2;
}
char *toke = perm;
char *temp;
//Status is set to 1 or 2
else if (status==1)
```

The `else` cannot compile there; the preceding statement is a variable declaration.  That makes it tricky to know what's going wrong.  It is very annoying to be given non-compilable code that claims to be running.  It makes it hard to know what can be trusted.

Your function can return `NULL` before this code, though — and the behaviour of `strdup(NULL)` is undefined, and so is the behaviour of `strcpy()` when told to copy from (or to) a `NULL` pointer.  You can't afford to play with the return value of `separatebetter()` until you've made sure it is not null.

The following code also repeats the memory leak problem:

```
{
    printf("here\n");
    temp=toke;
    char *temp1=malloc(strlen(temp)*sizeof(char));
    temp1=temp;
```

Again, maybe you intended to use `strcpy()`:

```
    strcpy(temp1, temp);
```

---

At the top of `separatebetter()`, you have:

```
static char* perm;
if (arr!=NULL)
{
    perm=arr;
}
if((perm[0]=='\0')||(perm[0]=='\n'))
{
    return NULL;
}
if (strcspn(perm, "<|>&")==0)
{
    status=1;
}
if (strcspn(perm, ";()")==0)
{
    status=2;
}
char *toke = perm;
```

The `static char *perm` is puzzling.  The assignment of `arr` to it sometimes is puzzling.  The use of `char *toke = perm;` is really puzzling.  The prior code does not always set `perm`, so sometimes it gets a pointer left over from a previous call to the function assigned to it.  That pointer might or might not still be valid.  I think you need to rethink the whole of `separatebetter()`.

Believe your tools!  (Especially believe `valgrind`!)

Comment: I edited the the curr initialization above, then tried to printf curr, and valgrind told me curr was not initialized. Am I wrong in thinking that the initialization in curr is the problem?

Comment: You need to fix the code so you're showing a compilable `separatebetter()` function.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I omitted a lot of the separatebetter code for brevity (there was an if before the else if, for instance). I appreciate the help.